# reading character for scanf when it is suppose to be an int

Tags: c, scanf

I'm using scanf to read in an int, however, I to make create an error if someone puts something other than an int. I have noticed that if I input a character for scanf("%d",%number);, it saves it as 0. I would like 0 to be an option. How do i avoid this issues?

the test code would be 
int number; 
   scanf("%d",&number);
   printf("%d",number);

Comment: Always check what [`scanf` ***returns***](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value). And remember that if `scanf` fails to match the input to the format, then it will return and leave the input untouched (to be read by the very next call to `scanf`). That's why it's recommended to read whole lines (using e.g. [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets)) and parse it using e.g. `sscanf` or [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol).

Answer (score 2):

Try this method to see if the entered input was a number `%d`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int number;

    if (scanf("%d", &number))
        printf("A number!\n");
    else
        printf("Not a number!\n");

    return 0;
}
```